# Advance Wars - Show Available Spaces

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to recreate the Nintendo game Advance Wars for a school project. I have the basics of the game done, however, I am unhappy with how I am moving my units. All units have a range that they can move, for example Infantry can move 5 spaces. I am currently moving the units by searching through all spaces in a diamond formation within their range, however, this does not account for the possibility of objects blocking their path to a space.

For example, in the [Current Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPMZN.png).
The space on the far left should not be available.

How would I go about highlighting the available spaces without showing spaces that are blocked by obstacles.

Any examples or help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking. what have you tried so far? show us some code!

Comment: Have you considered using a plain DFS/BFS? Should be sufficient for the use case you describe.

Comment: You could create a bi directional graph where nodes are tiles and edges are the cost to move between tiles for that unit. Start at the unit's location, and DFS/BFS out until your movement remaining is 0, and the nodes you reached are the tiles you can move to

Comment: Look up the flood fill algorithm. It could probably be adapted to work for this.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I used the flood fill algorithm and it worked perfectly, thanks